# PBKDF2 Key Derivative in Android Studio is not working

Tags: android, encryption, sha1, pbkdf2

I am trying to implement PBKDF2 with Hmac Sha1 in my android app for encrypting the password.
But the encoded key is too short and returns incorrect value comparing to what i get from https://8gwifi.org/pbkdf.jsp website.
Below is the code i use

```
  char [] salt="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa".toCharArray();
  byte [] serversalt="E4jmftOIsX4TYB6qPUuX6VteIKExLfgQ9I9DTY5VbOTRT7NGqrgc!1130053051!1657429480328".getBytes();
            try { 
       SecretKey sk=generateKey1(salt,serversalt);
       System.out.println("key:"+sk.getEncoded().toString());
                }catch (Exception e){ System.out.println(e.toString());


public static SecretKey generateKey1(char[] passphraseOrPin, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphraseOrPin, salt, 4, 128);
        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        return secretKey;
    }
```

Expected key is  7b3318d9fedb813a3c474ec043681fef
but i'm getting  [B@b5971bf

Comment: Now the code works. byte[] hash = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
            System.out.println( String.format("%x", new BigInteger(hash)));

Answer (score 0):

Try use:
SecretKey sk = generateKey1(salt,serversalt);
String key = Base64.encodeToString(sk.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
In my case is working and key is the same as i get from https://8gwifi.org/pbkdf.jsp website.